# Read Xlsx file from a string

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have an Xlsx file content in a string, loaded from the database.

Currently, I create the spreadsheet using a temp file:

```
file_put_contents($fileName, $bundle['package_blank']);
$wobook = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($fileName);
unlink($fileName);
```

Any way to read it directly from memory without having to write it in a temporary file?

Comment: did you get a solution for this question?

Comment: @Esteban, as I wrote, using a temporary file